# Performance Improvement due to Use Of If-then cases

Tags: c++

Below mentioned function has two arguments: string s and string t. The function tries to find if "string s" is present in "string t" or not. I successfully submitted the solution. But I found one thing which was particularly confusing for me. The last if-else condition decides whether it is a substring or not. If I remove the else condition(just use if condition and return false if the above condition is not satisfied), the code takes more time to run compared to the one containing if-else condition. What can be the reason for this?

```
bool isSubsequence(string s, string t) 
    {
        int s_len = s.length();
        int t_len = t.length();

        int tIndex = 0;
        int sIndex = 0;

        if(s_len > t_len)
        {
            return false;
        }

        while( (tIndex < t_len) && (sIndex < s_len) )
        {
            if(t[tIndex] == s[sIndex])
            {
                sIndex++;
            }
            tIndex++;
        }

        if(sIndex == s_len)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How much longer? Was your input the same? What was your input? How are you analyzing the run-time?

Comment: Are you testing optimized code? If not, do so. Testing unoptimized code for performance is pointless.

Comment: To be clear, are you asking about `if (sIndex == s_len){ return true; } else { return false; }` versus `if (sIndex == s_len){ return true; } return false;`? These two are completely equivalent and you should investigate where the performance difference is really coming from.

Comment: The entire if/then/else sequence could be replaced with `return (sIndex == s_len);`, btw.  Any performance differences are definitely not because of how the if/then/else logic is expressed, since the C++ compiler (assuming optimizations are enabled) will optimize any of the considered variations into the same form.

Comment: Unrelated: There may be performance advantages in passing by `const` reference. `bool isSubsequence(const string &s, const string &t) `. And there may not. Compilers are pretty smart.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, I am not sure if we can optimize that code more. But, I will look into it. @JeremyFriesner Thank you. I can use "return (sIndex == s_len) and as also mentioned in the below answer, regardless of what format we use, C++ Compiler will optimize into the same form. Thank you, once again.

Comment: You may want to use standard library functions rather than coding your own.  There is a possibility that the standard library functions have been optimized by the compiler writers and may take advantage of special instructions of your processor or architecture.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks. I was solving a Leetcode question so I thought I better use my own functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance differences you're observing have nothing to do with the code presented in this question.

The two code snippets you described produce exactly identical assembly code, as tested on [Godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/ipsjvq):

Version 1, using full if-else

```
#include<string>

using namespace std;

bool isSubsequence(string s, string t) 
{
    int s_len = s.length();
    int t_len = t.length();

    int tIndex = 0;
    int sIndex = 0;

    if(s_len > t_len)
    {
        return false;
    }

    while( (tIndex < t_len) && (sIndex < s_len) )
    {
        if(t[tIndex] == s[sIndex])
        {
            sIndex++;
        }
        tIndex++;
    }

    if(sIndex == s_len)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Version 2, dropping the else

```
#include<string>

using namespace std;

bool isSubsequence(string s, string t) 
{
    int s_len = s.length();
    int t_len = t.length();

    int tIndex = 0;
    int sIndex = 0;

    if(s_len > t_len)
    {
        return false;
    }

    while( (tIndex < t_len) && (sIndex < s_len) )
    {
        if(t[tIndex] == s[sIndex])
        {
            sIndex++;
        }
        tIndex++;
    }

    if(sIndex == s_len)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Assembly Code generated for BOTH code examples:

```
isSubsequence(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 40
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-40], rdi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-48], rsi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-40]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::length() const
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-28], eax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-48]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::length() const
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-32], eax
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], 0
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-24], 0
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-28]
        cmp     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-32]
        jle     .L2
        mov     eax, 0
        jmp     .L3
.L2:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
        cmp     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-32]
        jge     .L4
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        cmp     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-28]
        jge     .L4
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
        movsx   rdx, eax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-48]
        mov     rsi, rdx
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator[](unsigned long)
        movzx   ebx, BYTE PTR [rax]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        movsx   rdx, eax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-40]
        mov     rsi, rdx
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator[](unsigned long)
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rax]
        cmp     bl, al
        sete    al
        test    al, al
        je      .L5
        add     DWORD PTR [rbp-24], 1
.L5:
        add     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], 1
        jmp     .L2
.L4:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        cmp     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-28]
        jne     .L6
        mov     eax, 1
        jmp     .L3
.L6:
        mov     eax, 0
.L3:
        add     rsp, 40
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        ret
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::length() const:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax+8]
        pop     rbp
        ret
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator[](unsigned long):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], rsi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_data() const
        mov     rdx, rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
        add     rax, rdx
        leave
        ret
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_data() const:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax]
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Whatever is happening, it has nothing to do with this particular syntactical choice.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I should have checked this before.Will keep this in mind. Thank you once again.